# Removing outliers after performing a group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, statistics, outliers

This is my first post so please take it easy on me.

I am trying to plot a box chart for the Life Expectancy of every country from the year 2000 to 2015. My CSV file contains every country 16 times, 1 per year. I plotted the box using `df.boxplot(by=['Country'], column='Life Expectancy')` and I was able to see the outliers for the Life Expectancy from that. I was also able to get the quantile for each country by this `Q1 = df.groupby('Country')['Life Expectancy'].quantile(0.25)` `Q3 = df.groupby('Country')['Life Expectancy'].quantile(0.75)` I looked at many tutorials but none of them use the groupby so I'm stuck and unsure of what to do next. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi did either of these solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Define a function to return a dataframe with the `upper` and `lower` bound assuming you only need the IQR, `groupby`, then calculate the IQR, assign these columns to the `df`, finaly, do a query where the values are not outliers:

```
def fun(serie):
    return pd.DataFrame([[serie.quantile(0.25), serie.quantile(0.75)]]
                             *serie.shape[0], 
                        columns=['lower', 'upper'], 
                        index=serie.index)

df[['lower', 'upper']] = df.groupby('Country')['Life Expectancy'].apply(fun)

df = df.query('lower <= `Life Expectancy` <= upper')
    .drop(columns=['lower', 'upper'])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to remove outliers I would use zscore instead of quantile

```
from scipy import stats

df['outlier'] = (np.abs(stats.zscore(df['Life Expectancy'])) >= 3) # replace 3 with a threshold of your choice
new_df= df[df['outlier']==False].copy()
```

But since you want to do this on a groupby object you could use

```
df.groupby('Country')['Life Expectancy'].transform(lambda x : stats.zscore(x,ddof=1))
```

Comment: Nice solutions, didn't know zscore in scipy

Comment: Thanks! I like yours too!